# Are there any GPG checks in OpenBSD when installing an application?

Tags: package-management, openbsd, gpg

Like under an average Linux distribution - are there any checkings that the downloaded packages are really the packages that are on the mirror server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Packages fetched by `pkg_add` from [the official mirror sites](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#Mirror) are signed and the `pkg_add` utility will automatically check the signatures against the keys available on your system.

From [the `pkg_add` manual](http://man.openbsd.org/pkg_add):

```
 If a package is digitally signed:

 •   pkg_add checks that its signature is valid and that the signature was
     emitted by a valid signing key, as stored in /etc/signify/*-pkg.pub,

 •   pkg_add verifies that the compressed package data matches the
     signature, before it decompresses and unpacks files.
```

The signatures are not checked using GnuPG but with the native [`signify` utility](http://man.openbsd.org/signify).

---

Old (outdated) answer from 2011:

No, there are not. But see these threads from the openbsd-misc list:

- [package integrity, security and checks. .... where are they ?](http://marc.info/?t=122925041000001&r=1&w=2)
- [package and port paranoia](http://marc.info/?t=103760231500001&r=1&w=2)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can perform some checks, when you update the system! 
Check the `signify` command mentioned here:
https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#Download

You can get the SHA256.sig file from the [official mirror](https://ftp.OpenBSD.org/pub/OpenBSD/), under your version and architecture.

When you update, you need to check the new version's kernel signatures before booting it (and selecting `(U)pgrade`). After that, the updater does signature checking automatically for the rest of the system it installs.